# How do I assign each row of a data frame to its respective value from another data frame?

Tags: r

There are two data frames, DF_A and DF_B.

DF_A:

| domain | valid |
| --- | --- |
| googl.nl | 1 |
| hwenzl.de | 0 |
| aytqfis.com | 0 |
| tokzrrtss.es | 1 |
| cnn.net | 0 |

DF_B:

| domain | good_page |
| --- | --- |
| googl.nl | NA |
| googl.nl | NA |
| googl.nl | NA |
| googl.nl | NA |
| googl.nl | NA |
| googl.nl | NA |
| hwenzl.de | NA |
| hwenzl.de | NA |
| hwenzl.de | NA |
| aytqfis.com | NA |
| tokzrrtss.es | NA |
| tokzrrtss.es | NA |
| tokzrrtss.es | NA |
| tokzrrtss.es | NA |
| cnn.net | NA |
| cnn.net | NA |
| cnn.net | NA |
| cnn.net | NA |

I want to change `good_page` for each row in DF_B to the respective value in `valid` of DF_A. Using mutate caused an error and using a for loop didn't help either.

Comment: take a look at the match() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` piplines:

```
DF_B %>% right_join(DF_A)
```

gives

```
Joining, by = "domain"
# A tibble: 18 × 3
   domain       good_page valid
   <chr>        <lgl>     <dbl>
 1 googl.nl     NA            1
 2 googl.nl     NA            1
 3 googl.nl     NA            1
 4 googl.nl     NA            1
 5 googl.nl     NA            1
 6 googl.nl     NA            1
 7 hwenzl.de    NA            0
 8 hwenzl.de    NA            0
 9 hwenzl.de    NA            0
10 aytqfis.com  NA            0
11 tokzrrtss.es NA            1
12 tokzrrtss.es NA            1
13 tokzrrtss.es NA            1
14 tokzrrtss.es NA            1
15 cnn.net      NA            0
16 cnn.net      NA            0
17 cnn.net      NA            0
18 cnn.net      NA            0
```

which is the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DF_C <- left_join(DF_B, DF_A, by="domain")
```

Or maybe some of the *_join() function family: [9.2.3 Merging data frames with *_join()](https://jules32.github.io/r-for-excel-users/vlookup.html)